# Can a general formula be constructed for the first n terms of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any way to make an equation for the sum of the first n terms of this sequence, in terms of n and w? I was thinking of something like binomial expansion, however the terms are not identical so I am not sure how to proceed.

Here is the sequence

$$\frac1{(w)^2+1} + \frac1{(2w)^2+1} + \frac1{(3w)^2+1} + \
\frac1{(4w)^2+1} + \dots$$

[Original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3n1m.png)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2F%28n%5E2*x%5E2+%2B+1%29%2C+n%3D1%2C+k%29) gives an expression in terms of the digamma function. I'm not sure if a simpler expression can be found.

Comment: @AlannRosas I m pretty sure this is the best you can do without  additional assuptions on $w.$